# HTML not rendering inside Jade

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I'm building a website with node.js, express, angular.js and jade. I'm currently testing html tags on blog posts, wich don't seem to be working. [image]

I'm focusing on the heading for now. Why doesn't the browser render it as HTML? I have btw tested this in chrome but I had the same result. This is the jade code:

```
div(ng-repeat='post in posts')
  h3 
    |{{post.title}}
```

And this is the mongodb record (what is relevant):

```
"title": "<strong>This text is strong</strong>",
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive:

```
div(ng-repeat='post in posts')
  h3 
    span(ng-bind-html-unsafe='post.title')
```

Comment: Then the site loads blank because this is a angular variable